# Can I use webforms ui designer in DNN module development?

Tags: webforms, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

DNN newbie here. My apologies if this is a really dump question.

When I add a web forms user control to another project, I can just create the UI by drag&drop from the toolbox.

But when I add the same user control to a DNN module template, I can't drag&drop anything to the designer.

Is there a way to do this in DNN module development? Or I have to write raw html?

Comment: *I can just create the UI by drag&drop from the toolbox.* - please don't.

Comment: @Dai, why not, what's bad about it?

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms generates bloated, non-semantic and inefficient markup which is heavily tied into its own JavaScript framework. The more a project is tied to WebForms the harder it is to port to another platform. It's always best to do web work writing HTML by hand - you get a lot more control and it's always faster too because you spend less time fighting the environment. Finally, note that the HTML designer in Visual Studio is very old and does not correctly display modern HTML5 and CSS3 features.

Comment: @Dai, thanks. This WebForms thing is very new to me. Used to angularjs and dojo.

Comment: Avoid WebForms if you can. ASP.NET MVC is much better.